# How to get inserted rows db sqlite

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have this sql query

```
INSERT INTO profile (title, value, account_id) 
VALUES
(5, 'Wass', "wewewewwew"), -- HOMETOWN
(6, 'sadas', "sdsdadkf"), -- HOMETOWN
returning account_id AS result;
```

I need to convert it to sqlite and this is what I have done

```
INSERT INTO `public.profile` (title, value, account_id) 
VALUES
(5, 'Wass', "wewewewwew"), -- HOMETOWN
(6, 'sadas', "sdsdadkf"), -- HOMETOWN
```

But I need returned column in sqlite query as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite has no RETURNING clause or something similar, and it does not allow INSERT in CTE.

So the only solution is to SELECT by by values that have just been inserted:

```sql
INSERT INTO public.profile (title, value, account_id) 
VALUES
(5, 'Wass', "wewewewwew"),
(6, 'sadas', "sdsdadkf");

SELECT id 
FROM public.profile
WHERE (title, value, account_id) IN ( (5, 'Wass', "wewewewwew"),
                                      (6, 'sadas', "sdsdadkf") );
```

Or course this needs the whole inserted data or a part of it to be defined as UNIQUE by according index.

If no such unique constraint (i.e. some inserted data may be full duplicate of the data which is already present in a table), but there is no such duplicates in the values which are inserted, you may use

```sql
INSERT INTO public.profile (title, value, account_id) 
VALUES
(5, 'Wass', "wewewewwew"),
(6, 'sadas', "sdsdadkf");

SELECT MAX(id) id
FROM public.profile
WHERE (title, value, account_id) IN ( (5, 'Wass', "wewewewwew"),
                                      (6, 'sadas', "sdsdadkf") )
GROUP BY title, value, account_id;
```

If there are duplicates in inserted values... I don't know how to solve.

Comment: sqlite DOES have a RETURNING clause since version 3.35.0 (2021-03-12) (but with some limitations)
https://sqlite.org/lang_returning.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible in Sqlite. But you can use *last_insert_rowid()* which will return the *ROWID* of last inserted record.

```
select last_insert_rowid();
```

For last inserted account_id:

```
select account_id from profile where rowid=last_insert_rowid();
```

For all the account_ids inserted:

```
select account_id from profile;
```